# does exclusion + supervenience + pairing necessitate reductionism?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, physicalism

If one accepts the exclusion argument (no physical event has a non-physical cause), the supervenience argument (no mental event causes any other mental event), and the pairing problem (no physical event can cause a mental event due to the lack of any pairing spatial relation), would one be obligated to accept reductionist physicalism Well, of course we have to at least accept that there is physical-mental causation in order for the argument to work.

Comment: The third premise is very odd, I am not sure how physical events not causing mental events would still be physicalism, maybe you meant the converse? With just the first two premises physicalism does not follow, [anomalous monism](http://www.iep.utm.edu/anom-mon) is an alternative. But it does presuppose that mental events cause physical events. So perhaps one does get physicalism if that is ruled out.

Comment: @Conifold the supervenience argument establishes that mental events do not cause physical events. So by your own admission, this would lead to physicalism.

Comment: No, supervenience is not enough. Anomalous monism accepts both supervenience and mental-to-physical causality. But the [supervenience is weak](http://www.iep.utm.edu/anom-mon/#SH4a), and it is only token causality, Davidson denies the possibility of psycho-physical laws.

Comment: @Conifold the supervenience argument established that if one accepts mental-physical supervenience, mental-mental causation becomes overdetermined. Therefore mental events can only be causally efficacious if they cause the physical supervenience base of mental events.  But this is ruled out by the exclusion argument.

Comment: This argument doesn't work for Davidson's linguistic supervenience. To get causation twice over you need a "metaphysical" bridge between mental events and their supervenience base. Davidson denies any such bridge, supervenience applies only to predicates. Mental events are physical events as tokens, hence causally efficacious, but there are no laws connecting mental (as mental) to physical (as physical), hence no translation into "duplication". Kim's supervenience you are thinking of was designed to make the twice over argument work, but accepting it is to assume reductionism to begin with.

Comment: If all you are doing is accepting the arguments and not rationally assessing their truth value, what would obligate you? You are free to accept or reject anything regardless of any reasoning.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy How is this relevant? I'm evaluating whether all three argument in conjunction entail physicalism. Of course, to convince someone of the truth of physicalism, I would first have to convince them of the truth of the three arguments.

Comment: @Conifold Kim's supervenience does not entail reductionism. It entails either reductionism or epiphenomenalism.

Comment: Sure. I think more general counterexamples can be built as variations on the psychophysical parallelism. No causation in either direction, just "pre-established harmony" a la Leibniz and Spinoza. To make it more plausible rephrase that physical and mental describe the same events in different languages, so their relation is that of translation, not causation. Neither double causation nor epiphenomenalism are then meaningful, and supervenience isn't strong enough to rule it out. Davidson simply reserves a bit of priority for the physical, and postulates unreachability of actual translation.

Comment: @Conifold yeah, I thought of parallelism as a counterexample. That's why I stipulated that one of the premises is "there mental-physical causation."

Comment: You'll need something stronger concerning what "causation" is. If one takes the Humean view that it is a theoretical fiction standing for persistent empirical regularities it wouldn't be hard to meet your stipulation, as is it doesn't do much work. And it is not clear how to strengthen it without postulating reductionism by another name. Also, I am still unclear on the meaning of your last premise, "no physical event can cause a mental event". It would seem that by that you ruled out even reductionism itself.

Comment: @Conifold no physical event can cause a mental event, if mental events are not physical events. I'd define causation as a subset of instantiation. Namely, for x to cause y, is for x to instantiate y, but the inverse does not always hold true, of course. I'd say instantiation is subject to overdetermination, which would vindicate kim's supervenience argument; since, supervenience bases can't properly be said to cause their supervenient properties.

Comment: Why? Magnet is not a field but it causes magnetic field, etc. Does this mean that you allow causation from mental to physical but not the other way? This seems to reverse the [usual interpretation of Kim's argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mental-causation/#ComPhy), and is highly implausible, people may have doubts about mental causation but rarely that the physical affects the mental. Also, paradigmatic physical on physical causation, like pushing a ball, does not seem to be instantiation in any obvious sense.

Comment: @Conifold you're confusing the pairing argument with the supervenience argument. The pairing argument would entail that there cannot be any physical-mental causation if the mental is non physical (and thus non spatial) due to the lack of a pairing spatial relation. Pushing a ball instantiates specific relational properties of the ball; the ball is further away from you than it was before. So we can define causation as a form of instantiation involving temporal and spatial relations. though I think that disagreement over this will be mostly if not entirely linguistic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52217/discussion-between-conifold-and-user8083).

Answer (score 1):

(I deleted this answer because its basic interpretation of the quesion was wrong.  But most of its content is still germane.  So it is back.)

You still have the problem with positions like transcendental pantheism or Deism, who create a third (or even a fifth) substance.  For them, the mental may currently supervene upon the material, but only because the material supervenes upon the 'spiritual' or some other determinant with an internal will.

Many of them suppose that while the latter state is permanent, the former may not be.  That gives them a secularist eschatology and a notion of heaven, either as some adaptation of Nirvana or as union with an ultimate God.  Or it provides them with a theoretical understanding of will that is non-determinist in a universe that is statistically determined.  This is not *too* silly or arcane because folks just asked a question about it https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/36062/9166.

They derive support from the basic nondeterminism of matter, which suggests there is a lower-lying determining source.  (At least in spirit, for their logic is often kind of nutty, even when they are brilliant, q.v. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind where the third substance is 'information'.)

So I still think you need to add the requirement of dualism to get your argument started.

And you still have the problem with alternative notions of causality.

One, coming from positions as wide apart as Hume and the religious notions of 'maya and lila', is that the regularity of physical causation is an epiphenomenon of perception -- not really present, but agreed upon by all those trapped in a shared illusion for their own peace of mind.  (Like Folie-a-deux, but Folie à tous).  Thus, you may reduce the mental to the physical, only to have the physical reduced back to the mental on a different scale.

Another is the return to the Medieval Christian notion that cause is really primarily teleological, flowing backward from the intended outcome, and only holding together in the forward direction as a side effect of its ultimate convergence.

So you would still need a stronger version of your last admitted thesis that not only establishes physical causation of the mental, but physical causation of the physical.